# Proxy setting under xfce within virtual machine

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, xfce, proxy, desktop-environments

My Ubuntu is within a virtual machine.

When I log in with a Ubuntu session, the web browser works fine. But when I log in with an **Xfce** session, the web browser does not work… I try to *change proxy setting*, it gives me:

> When running Google Chrome under a supported desktop environment, the system proxy settings will be used. However, either your system is not supported or there was a problem launching your system configuration.
>
> But you can still configure via the command line. Please see `man google-chrome` for more information on flags and environment variables.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution 1

There's a command line option `--proxy-server` - so it should be possible to run chrome using a terminal window, using the command

```
google-chrome --proxy-server="<proxy-name>:<proxy-port>"
```

---

#### Solution 2

Another solution would be to [set the environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables):

```
http_proxy=<proxy-name>:<proxy-port>
https_proxy=<proxy-name>:<proxy-port>
export http_proxy
export https_proxy
google-chrome
```

Comment: You might be interested in [setting `auto_proxy` variable](https://askubuntu.com/a/867586/701034) with **proxy auto-config URL**.