# does xfce4 support automatic proxy configuration?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, xfce, proxy

I know it need manual set proxy in xfce4[How do I set systemwide proxy servers in Xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150210/how-do-i-set-systemwide-proxy-servers-in-xubuntu-lubuntu-or-ubuntu-studio?noredirect=1&lq=1) ,
but does it support url proxy like .pac url configuration? if does, how?

Comment: Sorry what does the desktop env have to do with automatic proxy config?

Comment: @Rinzwind  I am in a country can not use google, so I bought a vpn, it provide a proxy url like `http://dutai.com/ps.pac`, it can use in ubuntu unity,gnome,mate,kde,  I do not know how to use it in xfce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up auto_proxy/AUTO_PROXY variables in /etc/environment like:

```
auto_proxy="https://someurl.to/your.pac"
AUTO_PROXY="https://someurl.to/your.pac"
```

and logout/login after that.